# Having trouble with writing data in to two tables at the same time in MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller

I am working on an MVC problem, where the user will enter the data into the form, that would be stored in a sql database. Database already exists, has a lot of tables and it is connected with my asp.net. 
I iwish that input data will be saved into the correct table and correct row. Here is my attempt at the code. Data is trivial.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using My_App.Models;

namespace My_App.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            Database1 db = new Database1();

            List<User> list = db.User.ToList();
            ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(list, "id_car", "id_user", "name_user");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(Car model)
        {
            try
            {
               Database1 db = new Database1();

            List<User> list = db.User.ToList();
            ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(list, "id_car", "id_user", "name_user");

                Car cars = new Car();
cars.id_car = model.id_car;
cars.id_city = model.id_city;
cars.car_name = model.car_name;
db.Car.Add(cars);
db.SaveChanges;

      User users = new User();
users.id_car = model.id_car;
users.id_user = model.id_user;
users.name_user = model.name_user;
db.User.Add(users);
db.SaveChanges;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

View

```
        @model My_app.Models.Car
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
    {   
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
                 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            
                @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.id_car , new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                

                    @Html.EditorFor((model=>model.id_car  )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor((model=>model.id_car  )
                
            


            
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.car_name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.car_name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.car_name)
                
            

            
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name_user, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name_user)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name_user)
                
            

            
                
                    
                
            
          }
```

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [id_car]
    ,[id_city]
    ,[car_name]
  FROM [CarUsers].[dbo].[Car]

SELECT TOP (1000) [id_car]
    ,[id_user]
    ,[name_user]   
 FROM [CarUsers].[dbo].[User]
```

When I write only a controller for Car, it works (data is signed into my SQL table), but When I only write it for User it doesn't work (I changed the model into User)
I also tried with MultipleClass..also doesn't t work. I can't grasp the situation of the problem and where error occurs. I wish data to be written into two tables at the same time.
Thanks for your time and useful advice. Best regards.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? What goes wrong? What errors do you get, and on which line? What debugging have you tried?

Comment: P s. As an aside, this code: `catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }` is completely pointless. Unless you're planning to add value by logging the exception and/or displaying some custom error message then all you're doing here is wasting CPU time

Comment: I don't know how to define the second table in the controller (also to be connected with the first one), that I could call both tables inside the view.       users.id_user = model.id_user;
users.name_user = model.name_user;  is not right, because id_user and name_user are not part of Car table

Comment: I think you maybe need to learn about the concept of a ViewModel which can incorporate properties from different parts of the data model, in order to display them all in your page. Normally you wouldn't make a DB class the model of your View directly. You can google lots of articles about it, but this one gives a very simple example of the idea: https://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/viewmodels

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 
This is a great article :) it explains a lot

I've changed the code into

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using My_App.Models;

namespace My_App.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            Database1 db = new Database1();
              List<MyClass> MyClassList = new List<MyClass>();

            var details = (from c in db.Car
                           join u in db.User on c.id_car equals u.id_car
                           select new { c.id_car, c.id_city, c.car_name, u.id_user,u.name_user }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in details)
            {
                MyClass mC = new MyClass();
                mC.id_car = item.id_car;
                mC.id_city = item.id_city;
                mC.car_name = item.car_name;
                mC.id_user = item.id_user;
                mC.name_user = item.name_user;
                MyClassList.Add(mC); MyClassList.Add(mC);
              }

           return View(MyClassList);
        }
```

View

```
 @model IEnumerable<My_app.Models.MyClass>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
        {   
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-horizontal">


            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                 @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.id_car , new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.id_car )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.id_car )
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.car_name , new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.car_name )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.car_name )
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.name_user, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.name_user)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.name_user)
                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

I now need to find out how to post and save input data from MYClass into a single table (Car and User). I guess the problem is hidden in the Controller and connect with. Add?